# Why is column-wise computation faster than computation on whole DataFrame in Pandas when computing Euclidean distance

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a pandas Series which contains *x* and *y* coordinate of a point *p* and a DataFrame which contains several points *q<sub>1</sub>* to *q<sub>n</sub>* (also *x* and *y*). I then compute the pairwise Euclidean distances between *p* and each of the *qs*. I tried several approaches of computation in an effort to find the most efficient one, of which two caught my eye:

```py
import pandas as pd

cs = pd.DataFrame([[10, 15], [56, 45], [33, 24]], columns=['x', 'y'])
pt = pd.Series({'x': 14, 'y': 32})

def d1(cls, pt):
    return ((pt['x'] - cls['x']) ** 2 + (pt['y'] - cls['y']) ** 2) ** 0.5

def d2(cls, pt):
    return ((pt - cls) ** 2).sum(axis=1) ** 0.5
```

The first one, `d1`, subtracts and squares the *x* and *y* columns separately and then adds them, while `d2` subtracts both columns at the same time for subtraction and then uses `.sum()` to add them.

I expected `d2` to be faster, but when using `timeit` on both functions (7 runs, 1000 loops each) I found that `d1` is nearly three times faster than `d2` (690 ms vs 1.9 s).

What could be a reason for that?

Comment: Can't help you so much with the logic, but I can tell you that it's not unique to `sum()`. Vectorization is always faster than pandas' built in functions.

Comment: @Aryerez You are generally correct, but OP is using pandas' `sum` (which is presumably vectorized), not the built-in `sum`

Comment: @DeepSpace I edited it to make my intention more clear.

Comment: On my machine the execution time difference is rather marginal (when running `timeit` on just the `d1` and `d2` function code): for `d1` the result is `29.2 ns ± 0.123 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)` and for `d2` the result is `27.2 ns ± 0.724 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)`.

Comment: I would have expected marginal differences, after all d1 is doing what d2 should be doing under the hood if everything is well optimized.

Comment: There are three operations here (subtraction, multiplication, summation), one could time them independently to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the poorer performance of `d2` is the addional overhead of organizing the data frame operations (index checking an alignment etc.) Although I'm not able to explain every detail you'll get the basic idea from the profile charts  for [d1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqzBc.png) and [d2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSTGS.jpg).

The difference between `d1` and `d2` will get smaller with increasing dimensionality: on my machine I get a `d2`/`d1` execution time ratio of 2.6, 2.1 and 1.8 for 2, 3 and 4 dimensions, respectively. So I guess for a high enough number of dimensions `d2` will probably be faster than `d1` (not tested).

The **fastest way** to compute the Euclidean distance is using [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) from `SciPy`:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

def d3(cls, pt):
    return pd.Series(distance.cdist(cls, [pt]).ravel())
```

It's minimum 5 times faster than `d1` and practically doesn't depend on the number of dimensions. 
The following is my `timeit` output for `d1`, `d2` and `d3` for 2, 3 and 4 dimensions:

```
2D
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.61 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 246 µs per loop
3D
100 loops, best of 3: 2.05 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.28 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 234 µs per loop
4D
100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.06 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 237 µs per loop
```

As you can see from the performance plot for the original 2D case, the difference between `d1` and `d2` also gets smaller with increasing dataframe size:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! What tool did you use to create the profile charts?